# What specific hash algorithm does MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA") return?

Tags: java, cryptography, undefined-behavior

`MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")` seems to work and gives me a `MessageDigest`, but I can't tell what algorithm it's giving me.

Is it SHA-1 or SHA-0 or ..?

---

I'm not interested in what happens on my machine. I want to know whether it will return sha0 or sha1 for all valid implementations of Java (or it's undefined).

Comment: The easy way to figure it out would be to use whatever is returned to hash the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" and examine the output. If you get `2fd4e1c6-7a2d28fc-ed849ee1-bb76e739-1b93eb12` then you have SHA-1. Lee Meador's answer shows a programatic way of seeing what `SHA` is an alias for.

Comment: @NikBougalis, did you also check if the same output happens for both sha-0 and sha-1? How do I know they are likely to be different? I can't even find a description of sha-0 anywhere.

Comment: @NikBougalis citation needed

Comment: *shakes head* if you are so inclined, check out http://www.cc.utah.edu/~nahaj/ada/sha/sha-0/ for an implementation of `SHA-0`, grab it, compile it, execute it and test it yourself. The fact is that `SHA-1` performs a barrel roll where `SHA-0` didn't. This significantly changes the output of o the algorithm (if for no other reason because of the avalanche effect). It would an *amazing* coincidence if any string hashed to the same value using both `SHA-0` and `SHA-1`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [JCE Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#AppA) lists standard names that an implementation is expected to support. "SHA-1" is specified, as are SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512. "SHA", "SHA-0" and SHA-2" are not standard names and therefore may not be supported at all. You cannot guarantee what "SHA" will return, if anything at all, because it is not in the standard.

Comment: Very good answer. Never leave anything like this in doubt and use the real name, not an "alias" and if possible, never leave anything to default values either (e.g. always specify `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` as `"AES"` will return ECB mode encryption for `Cipher.getInstance()` in the SunJCE implementation).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. So in other words, the answer to my actual question is "neither/undefined".

Comment: If I understand this issue correctly, then what you refer to is "standard names", for example "SHA-384" and "SHA-512" that may be used. But in no way is the Java platform required to support these algorithms. JavaDoc of [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) and [this url](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html) (google "must support") both say that SHA-256 is required, but not SHA-384 or SHA-512.

Comment: This [Java™ Cryptography Architecture API Specification & Reference](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#AppA) from 1997 specifies that **SHA** is the same as **SHA-1**.

The Java 7 version from 2014 moves the declarations to [Java™ Cryptography Architecture
Standard Algorithm Name Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html), but lists **SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512** for MessageDigest.

Answer (score 19):

SHA-0 is obsolete. For use with the Java JCE MessageDigest, SHA == SHA-1 for some JCE providers. By the way, SHA-1 is not considered to be secure with today's computers and technology. SHA-512 is still secure for pretty much anything. SHA-256 is ok for most things, still.

You can list the protocols available in the Java version you are using with this code. (I got it [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/jce.html) ):

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;

public class JceLook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Algorithms Supported in this JCE.");
        System.out.println("====================");
        // heading
        System.out.println("Provider: type.algorithm -> className" + "\n  aliases:" + "\n  attributes:\n");
        // discover providers
        Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
        for (Provider provider : providers) {
            System.out.println("<><><>" + provider + "<><><>\n");
            // discover services of each provider
            for (Provider.Service service : provider.getServices()) {
                System.out.println(service);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

It will show information like this for all the various algorithms available. (Note that this is actual output from the program above for some update level of Oracle/Sun Java 6 and it shows that SHA is equivalent to SHA-1 and SHA1. You can pass any of the three strings to MessageDigest and get the same result. But this depends on the Cryptography Provider (the JCE) and might not be the same.)

```
SUN: MessageDigest.SHA -> sun.security.provider.SHA
  aliases: [SHA-1, SHA1]
  attributes: {ImplementedIn=Software}
```

If you load additional providers (e.g. BouncyCastle) it will show those too.

Comment: I'm not interested in what happens on my machine. I want to know whether it will return sha0 or sha1 for all valid implementations of Java (or it's undefined).

Comment: I suspect it's undefined, but I very much doubt that *any* implementation of Java would return `SHA-0`. It was withdrawn after a design flaw was discovered and corrected, producing `SHA-1`.

Comment: "But this depends on the Cryptography Provider (the JCE) and might not be the same." WTF. Then how can you ever be sure you're calling the right hash function? @NikBougalis I'd be a bit surprised since I don't know any applications that require SHA-0, but better be safe than sorry.

Comment: Its undefined to tell you the cold hard truth. But its true that SHA == SHA1 for the JCEs that come with Oracle/Sun Java and WebLogic JRocket (at least for Java 6) and, as I recall, IBM's JCE used with WebSphere.

Comment: Sorry @megazord. Cryptography is a place where you have to be meticulous. Why not just use SHA-1 instead of SHA to make sure you either get the algorithm or get an exception?

Comment: @Lee Meador: I never said I'm using SHA or even SHA-1. I am analyzing some existing code. I should not have to reason for more than 1 second about **which** cryptographic hash I'm using. In C this would be easy to find out, `junk = Sha_Init()`, I simply look at the source/doc of the function I'm calling, it doesn't "abstract away from me the trouble of knowing which hash I'm using", Java Crypto API does.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know full well that getInstance("SHA") should not be used and I would not use it in my own code. However I found this in some legacy code and wanted to know the exact algorithm being used. Your answer was really helpful, thanks.