# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: internal error: SHA-1 not available

Tags: java, android-studio, centos7

I try to start Android Studio under CentOS and the fowllowing message showed up

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: internal error: SHA-1 not available.
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.init(SecureRandom.java:108)
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:79)
at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:198)
at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:162)
at java.util.UUID$Holder.<clinit>(UUID.java:96)
at java.util.UUID.randomUUID(UUID.java:142)
at com.intellij.internal.statistic.analytics.StudioCrashDetection.start(StudioCrashDetection.java:46)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:82)

Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA MessageDigest not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:167)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.init(SecureRandom.java:106)
    ... 7 more
```

I verified that I have JDK from Oracle jdk-8u161-linux-x64.rpm installed,JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161" JRE_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre,jsse.jar is present in jre/lib/.
What else can be wrong?

Comment: This must be a configuration error of some sort. This question suggest it might be class loader specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334751/weird-behaviour-of-custom-system-classloader-and-messagedigest  . This github ticket suggest re-installing the JDK solved the problem: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1638

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resolved by Installing another Version of Android Studio.The one I have problem with is android-studio-ide-171.4443003-linux and I replace it with android-studio-ide-173.4670197-linux.zip the problem disappears.It neither has problem with Android Studio 2.Still hope someone can explain this.