# Can any one help me to understand why I'm getting two different Key hashes?

Tags: java, facebook, hash

I found two different methods to get the key hash for an android application:

#### 1. Using a Java method:

```
 public void generateHashkey() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "package_name",//TODO: change to your package name.
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("Signature", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                    Base64.NO_WRAP));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Signature", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d("Signature", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

#### 2. Fetch form Keystore:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias alias_name -keystore keystore_path | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Now my question is: I'm getting two different key hash from these two methods, why so?

If these methods return two different hashes, which one should I use?

As I register my app on FB with hash generated by using the 2nd method and when I try FB login in my app(live/production) it is asking for hash generated by the 1st method.

Comment: Thanks @Dragonthoughts, I got it.

Comment: I've moved the comments to become an answer. If it solved your problem then please accept it as your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly using different hashing algorithms? Your code shows you are using one version of the SHA hash your command line is specifically asking for SHA1?

This discussion of hashing options may help you.

[What specific hash algorithm does MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA") return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903539/what-specific-hash-algorithm-does-messagedigest-getinstancesha-return)